# Remove escape characters from Azure Data Explorer JSON object in Azure Data Factory

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer, adx

I trying to export the results of an ADX query into a JSON file using ADF. I have tried using the copy activity to map the data directly from the query to the blob storage dataset. Two of the columns that are being returned are 'dynamic' type in ADX, and such should be output as a JSON object in the file.

The input for the query looks as required, with no additional characters:

[image: Input Dataset Definition]

[image: Preview of data]

The below image is the top of the properties column (column 5), showing the opening of the object bracket.

[image: Properties object column]

The output file only contains additional escape and line return characters within the properties object data that is returned. The Build, TypeName and other key and value pair columns are not affected.

[image: Modified output column]

I need to be able to return this data in JSON format without any of the additional characters. Any ideas on how I could achieve this within ADF?

UPDATE:
Having tested with Azure Data Studio and exporting the data directly to JSON from the application, it seems that the KQL is the issue. When I use parse_json(Properties) I receive the same /r/n and /" characters as before. When I use extractjson("$",tostring(Properties)) I see a slight improvement, but the " are still escaped \ "

[image]

Comment: Also checkout function [`unescape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#unescape)  in DataFlow and function [`json()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#json) in ADF pipeline expressions

Comment: were you able to find a way around this ?

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below query:

```
SETEL_Objects | project ID, FullName, parse_json(properties) | take 50
```

Refer official MS docs for more details: [todynamic(), parse_json()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction)

Comment: Thanks Karthik, I have determined that the problem is in my query and not in ADF, as when I export directly from Azure Data Studio, I see the same problem with the additional characters.

I have added some content to the original post about what parse_json and extractjson are doing.

Comment: The answer hasn't solved my issue just yet, unfortunately. I still have the unwanted characters in my output. I have just identified that the issue is with the KQL output, not the EDF output. Do you have any more suggestions that might help? Thanks